# Using dynamic parameters in email publisher subjectSettings block with CruiseControl.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to get dynamic parameters to be used in the email 
publisher's subjectSettings block.  For example,

```
<project> 
    ... 
    <parameters> 
      <textParameter> 
        <name>version</name> 
        <display>Version to install</display> 
        <description>The version to install.</description> 
        <required>true</required> 
      </textParameter> 
   </parameters> 
   <tasks> 
   ... 
   </tasks> 
   <publishers> 
   .... 
   <email includeDetails="TRUE"> 
        <from>buildmaster</from> 
        <mailhost>localhost</mailhost> 
        <users> 
          <user name="Joe" group="buildmaster" address="jdavies" /> 
        </users> 
        <groups> 
          <group name="buildmaster"> 
            <notifications> 
              <notificationType>Always</notificationType> 
            </notifications> 
          </group> 
          <group name="users"> 
            <notifications> 
              <notificationType>Success</notificationType> 
              <notificationType>Fixed</notificationType> 
            </notifications> 
          </group> 
        </groups> 
        <subjectSettings> 
          <subject buildResult="Success" value="Version ${version} 
installed." /> 
          <subject buildResult="Fixed" value="Version ${version} fixed 
and installed." /> 
        </subjectSettings> 
        <modifierNotificationTypes> 
          <notificationType>Success</notificationType> 
        </modifierNotificationTypes> 
      </email> 
   </project>
```

I have tried using ${version} and $[version].  When I use $[version], 
the entire subject line is empty!

For example, instead of seeing at least "Version BLANK installed.", I see only an empty subject line:

```
[Install:INFO] Emailing "" to joe
```

Are dynamic parameters supported in this case, and if so, what am I 
doing wrong?

Comment: What version of CC.Net are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.5.7256.1.

Comment: Your parameters block does not have a default.  If you put in a default does your email at least contain that default in the subject?

Comment: I added a default to the parameter but I still don't see anything.

Comment: Try wrapping things in the dynamicValues tag rather than just the parameter tag.  Update your example above to reflect your changes.

Comment: Look at this (http://bit.ly/bbdX3d) post in a google forum for CC.Net to see her sample

Comment: You could also look at this http://bit.ly/c0Bgd4 thread as she claims that 1.6 solves problems with DynamicData

Comment: Thanks Nick!!!  That was it.  I installed 1.6.7349.5 on my Dev machine and it works like a charm using the typical format $[parameter].

Please put your comment as an answer saying to upgrade to 1.6 and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments provided, I upgraded from CC.Net 1.5.7256.1 to 1.6.7349.5. Version 1.6 seems to be working OK.

The proper format for the parameters is $[parameter], as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for "dynamicValues" (only supported in v1.5 and greater) as configuration elements.

[Email Publisher Documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Email+Publisher)
[Dynamic Values Documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Direct+Dynamic+Value)

From the doucmenation (Example in context)

```
<project name="Test Project">
  <sourcecontrol type="svn">
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
  </sourcecontrol>
  <triggers>
     <intervalTrigger />
  </triggers>
  <tasks>
     <nant>
       <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
       <buildArgs>Help</buildArgs>
       <dynamicValues>
          <directValue property="buildArgs" parameter="CommandToRun" default="Help" />
       </dynamicValues>
     </nant>
     <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
  </tasks>
  <publishers>
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
  </publishers>
  <parameters>
    <!-- Omitted for brevity -->
  </parameters>
```

Comment: Nick - How would I use the dynamic values array in combination with the dynamic parameters block?